# Showing error in release mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my application I had added Listpicker and Datepicker with proper DLL and Namespaces while I build in debug mode it runs well but in Release mode it is showing error in the generated page(Mainpage.g.i.cs). The error message is "The type or namespace name 'ListPicker' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too on one project, and all I did was change from debug to release.

I fixed it by simply removing the mentioned references that are creating a problem and added them again to the project (just simple dll or via NuGet, whichever you're using). That solved it.

Comment: I can only guess, because it doesn't always happen. I'm glad it worked for you too ;)