# SQLite Client could not be found on release configuration

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I'm preparing to submit by app to marketplace and I wanted to run 'Marketplace Test Kit'. I've read some articles and as it was there I changed active config to Release|Any CPU.

When I want to rebuild I get couple of problems with references connected with SQLClient which I use in my app. Normally everything is working well. Just when I switch from debug to release they appears:

```
The type or namespace name 'SQLiteClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And I places when he shows I have defined them like that:

```
using SQLiteClient;
```

Reference is added as Community.Csharp.Sqlite.WP

Answer (score 0):

Oh, poor me ;)

I just deleted/added again the dll and that worked!

[Showing error in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414994/showing-error-in-release-mode)

Topic above with similar problem

Comment: This is a bit old, but does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I am having a similar problem that does not seem to respond to simply removing and re-adding the reference...